How can I access a file stored on a Google Shared Drive in Google Workspace using the API?
I can access files stored on a standard Google Shared Drive with no issues as an "editor" using the API, however I can't access files stored on a Google Shared Drive in Google Workspace even as "manager" using the API.
Why? How to solve this?
I have tried using the Google Drive API to access files stored on a Google Shared Drive within Google Workspace. Despite having "manager" permissions on the Workspace Shared Drive, I was unable to access the files via the API. I expected that having "manager" permissions would allow me to access and manipulate these files without any issues, similar to how I can access files on a standard Google Shared Drive with "editor" permissions.
I was hoping the API access would be seamless across both standard and Workspace Shared Drives, but that hasn't been the case. I have checked my API credentials, ensured that the necessary permissions are granted, and even re-authenticated my access, but the issue persists.
Here is the updated script:
import os
import openai
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import shutil

# OpenAI API Configuration
openai.api_key = 'API-key-here'

# Supported file formats for transcription
SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']

# Function to authenticate and get an instance of Google Drive
def authenticate_google_drive():
    try:
        gauth = GoogleAuth()
        # Try to load saved credentials
        gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
        if gauth.credentials is None:
            # Local authentication
            gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
        elif gauth.access_token_expired:
            # Refresh expired token
            gauth.Refresh()
        else:
            # Authorize the existing token
            gauth.Authorize()
        # Save the credentials
        gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
        return GoogleDrive(gauth)
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to authenticate Google Drive: {e}")

# Authenticate and get a Google Drive instance
try:
    drive = authenticate_google_drive()
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

# Input and result folder IDs
input_folder_id = 'ID-here'
result_folder_id = 'ID-here'

# Function to verify the existence of a folder
def verify_folder_exists(folder_id):
    try:
        folder = drive.CreateFile({'id': folder_id})
        folder.FetchMetadata(fields='title')
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error verifying folder with ID {folder_id}: {e}")

try:
    if not verify_folder_exists(input_folder_id):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Input folder with ID {input_folder_id} not found or access denied.")
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

try:
    if not verify_folder_exists(result_folder_id):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Result folder with ID {result_folder_id} not found or access denied.")
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

# Function to download files from the input folder and its subfolders
def download_files_from_drive(folder_id, destination_folder):
    try:
        query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"
        file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': query}).GetList()
        if not os.path.exists(destination_folder):
            os.makedirs(destination_folder)
        for file in file_list:
            if file['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                # Create subfolder locally and download files within it
                subfolder_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file['title'])
                os.makedirs(subfolder_path, exist_ok=True)
                download_files_from_drive(file['id'], subfolder_path)
            else:
                file_ext = file['title'].split('.')[-1].lower()
                if file_ext in SUPPORTED_FORMATS:
                    print(f"Downloading file {file['title']}...")
                    file.GetContentFile(os.path.join(destination_folder, file['title']))
                else:
                    print(f"File {file['title']} is not in a supported format and will be skipped.")
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error downloading files from folder with ID {folder_id}: {e}")

# Function to transcribe files using Whisper
def transcribe_files(input_folder, output_folder):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    for root, _, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for filename in files:
            input_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            output_subfolder = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.relpath(root, input_folder))
            os.makedirs(output_subfolder, exist_ok=True)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_subfolder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.txt')
            try:
                with open(input_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
                    response = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
                    with open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
                        output_file.write(response['text'])
                print(f"Transcription of {filename} saved in {output_path}")
            except openai.error.OpenAIError as oe:
                print(f"OpenAI API error transcribing {filename}: {oe}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unknown error transcribing {filename}: {e}")

# Function to upload transcribed files to the result folder
def upload_files_to_drive(folder_id, source_folder):
    try:
        for root, _, files in os.walk(source_folder):
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                rel_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, source_folder)
                parents = [{'id': folder_id}]
                # Create subfolders on Google Drive if necessary
                for subfolder in rel_path.split(os.sep)[:-1]:
                    folder_query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false and title='{subfolder}' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
                    folder_list = drive.ListFile({'q': folder_query}).GetList()
                    if not folder_list:
                        new_folder = drive.CreateFile({'title': subfolder, 'parents': parents, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'})
                        new_folder.Upload()
                        folder_id = new_folder['id']
                    else:
                        folder_id = folder_list[0]['id']
                    parents = [{'id': folder_id}]
                file_drive = drive.CreateFile({'title': filename, 'parents': parents})
                file_drive.SetContentFile(file_path)
                file_drive.Upload()
                print(f"File {filename} uploaded to the result folder.")
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error uploading file {filename} to folder with ID {folder_id}: {e}")

# Temporary paths for download and upload
temp_download_folder = './downloaded_files'
temp_transcribed_folder = './transcribed_files'

# Executing the process
try:
    print(f"Downloading files from folder {input_folder_id} to {temp_download_folder}...")
    download_files_from_drive(input_folder_id, temp_download_folder)

    print(f"Transcribing files from folder {temp_download_folder} to {temp_transcribed_folder}...")
    transcribe_files(temp_download_folder, temp_transcribed_folder)

    print(f"Uploading transcribed files to folder {result_folder_id}...")
    upload_files_to_drive(result_folder_id, temp_transcribed_folder)

    # Cleaning up temporary files
    shutil.rmtree(temp_download_folder)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_transcribed_folder)

    print("Process completed successfully!")
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
    exit(1)


About however I can't access files stored on a Google Shared Drive in Google Workspace even as "manager" using the API., can I ask you about the details of your current issue? Can you provide the error message? And, where does the error occur in your script?

Sure, this is the error message:
Erro ao verificar a pasta com ID 1Wd8z2J3cKu2IYDSOG7m5V6ue2w8U5vcU: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1Wd8z2J3cKu2IYDSOG7m5V6ue2w8U5vcU?fields=title&alt=json returned "File not found: 1Wd8z2J3cKu2IYDSOG7m5V6ue2w8U5vcU". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: 1Wd8z2J3cKu2IYDSOG7m5V6ue2w8U5vcU', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'file', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

I updated the code to get specific error messages. If you need more details, please let me know.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the error line in your script. Where is the error line in your showing script?

I think the main error message is inside the link:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1Wd8z2J3cKu2IYDSOG7m5V6ue2w8U5vcU?fields=title&alt=json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}


Thank you for replying. Where is the error line in your showing script?

"The error in the script occurs in the verify_folder_exists function. Specifically, it is triggered at the line where the script tries to fetch the metadata of the folder to verify its existence:
folder.FetchMetadata(fields='title')

This line attempts to fetch the folder's metadata using its ID. If the folder ID is incorrect or the script does not have permission to access the folder, an HttpError 404 is raised, indicating that the file (in this case, the folder) was not found. This results in the error message you encountered."

Of course, does this text answer your question? I asked ChatGPT for help to give a more precise answer. I  updated the script in the post as well.
